# [up/down]case-region: Skip read-only text; Operate on read-write text; No Error

Tags: text-properties

The buffer contains a mixture of text that is read-only (with `'read-only` text properties) and read-write (i.e., no `'read-only` text properties).  I want to [up/down]case-region as to the read-write sections, but am unable to do so due to the `'read-only` sections.  How can I [up/down]case everything that is read-write within the defined BEG/END of the region, skipping the read-only text, and not yielding any error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this command:

```
(defun on-writeable-portions (fn beg end)
  "Call FN on all writeable subregions of BEG - END."
  (interactive "CCommand: \nr")
  (when (get-text-property beg 'read-only)
    (setq beg (next-single-property-change beg 'read-only nil (1+ end))))
  (while (< beg end)
    (let ((lim (next-single-property-change beg 'read-only nil (1+ end))))
      (funcall fn beg (1- lim))
      (setq beg
            (if (< lim end)
                (next-single-property-change lim 'read-only nil (1+ end))
              end)))))
```

Comment: The use-case of this function will undoubtedly vary.  In my particular use case, there is a `wdired-mode` buffer with a variety of files containing absolute paths.  The filename-non-directory is read-only along with the the file-attributes, but the base-file-name is read-write.  The function `on-writeable-portions` skips the last letter of the base-file-name at the end of each line in the region.  I don't know whether my workaround creates issues with other applications, but the workaround I chose was to change `(1- lim)` to just `lim`.  With that change, it works as expected.

Comment: ... I checked the text properties at the end of the line and that is where `read-only` begins anew; i.e., just before `\n` and just after the last character on the line (which in my case is the tail end of the base-file-name).  I may decide to go ahead and modify the `wdired-mode` code to begin `read-only` at the beginning of the next line so that the `\n` has no text properties, but I'll probably also keep the modification in the previous comment.  You have been a big help and I've added your function to a couple of keyboard shortcuts in `wdired-mode` ...

Comment: I have since changed the mod from `(1- lim)` to `lim` to `(min lim (point-max))`, the latter of which avoids an args-out-of-range if the region extends to the end of the buffer ...

Comment: I'm glad you could fix the off-by-one error and the bug at the end of the buffer, @lawlist, I didn't do much testing before answering.